# Setting Rotation of ExportWebMap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping, printing

I see from the [ExportWebMap specification](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004w8000000) that rotation can be set in the JSON object sent to the sever.

Does anyone know if this can be accessed via the ESRI JavaScript API (v3.9)?

I do not need to display the map with a rotation, just honor it in a printout

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JS API doesn't expose the ability to set a rotation property on the exported map directly, but its not too difficult to intercept the request and add the property manually.

```
    esriRequest.setRequestPreCallback(myCallbackFunction);

    function myCallbackFunction(ioArgs) {          
      //make sure we're only manipulating print requests
      if (ioArgs.url === "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute") {          
        //insert information about rotation into the webmap JSON string immediately after "'mapOptions':{"
        var output = ioArgs.content.Web_Map_as_JSON.substr(0, 15) + '"rotation": 45,' + ioArgs.content.Web_Map_as_JSON.substr(15);
        ioArgs.content.Web_Map_as_JSON = output;
      }

      // don't forget to return ioArgs.
      return ioArgs;
    }
```

its a bit hackish, but it works
http://jsfiddle.net/jagravois/tg27f/

check out the documentation for esriRequest.[setRequestPreCallback()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.request-amd.html#esrirequest.setrequestprecallback) for more information

Comment: Could I use the same logic you have suggested above, but instead of adjusting the map's rotation, change the exported map's scale?

Comment: I don't see why not, but it'd probably be worth calling JSON.parse() to dig out and manipulate the value that's already there